# Why does SP2013 "Add a Page" place the page in parent site instead of current subsite?

Tags: 2013, publishing-page

I'm surprised to discover that in the context of a Publishing site, the Site Action "Add A Page" puts the page in the Pages library of the PARENT site collection, even when the current site is a subsite (and also a Publishing site).

Is there any way (short of building a custom action) to change the behaviour of "Add a Page" so that the page is placed in the current (sub)site instead?

Comment: Are you sure? You are not using Managed navigation so that it looks like a subsite structure, but really is a flat structure on one site?

Comment: What does the "Find it at:***" say when you are inside the Add a page dialog ? Does it give you the correct url to the subsite ?

Comment: Robert: yes, I'm absolutely sure. I navigate to the subsite, then try to add the page.

Comment: Cameron: no, it doesn't. It gives me the url to the parent site collection.

Comment: I *am* using Managed Metadata navigation, but there's a real subsite structure behind it (thanks to a few intractable mistakes put in play before I arrived, but that's a longer story). I wonder if that has a bearing on what's happening.

Comment: Hmmm ... just enabling Managed Metadata navigation - regardless of site/subsite structure - causes this to happen. There doesn't seem to be an easy way to influence this, short of switching off Managed Metadata navigation.

Comment: If I keep the subsites from inheriting Managed Metadata navigation (or switch of Managed Metadata navigation entirely), I get more or less what I want. 

Part of the problem is that the "Find it at ..." field is calculated on the client. Although there's a way of changing the destination in an event receiver, there's no easy way of updating this field. More than anything else, it's this field that's supposed to give the customer visual confirmation of where the page is supposed to go.

Comment: I used Managed Navigation. Have subsites. Adding a page using 'Add a page' creates an url on rootsite collection. However the actual page is created in the subsite as it should. So the friendly url is (re)directing to the page in the subsite.